# Can I use ICC (Intraclass Correlation) as a decision criteria to use a model with random intercepts or a model with random intercepts and slopes?

Tags: intraclass-correlation

I am thinking on using a ICC as a decision criteria for choosing a mixed model with different random structures in r

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(distinct_pairs)) {
    dat1 <- datab

    model1 <- glmer(data = dat1, formula = var ~ condition + (condition|group), family = Gamma(link = "log"))
    model2 <- glmer(data = dat1, formula = var ~ condition + (1|group), family = Gamma(link = "log"))

#Calculate intraclass correlation so the model specification can be decided

    vars1 <- lapply(summary(model1)$varcor,diag)
vars2 <- lapply(summary(model2)$varcor,diag)
    resid_var1 <- attr(summary(model1)$varcor, "sc")^2
resid_var2 <- attr(summary(model2)$varcor, "sc")^2
    total_var1 <- sum(sapply(vars1, sum), resid_var1)
    total_var2 <- sum(sapply(vars2, sum), resid_var2)
    ICCmodel1 <- sapply(vars1, sum)/total_var1#random slopes & intercepts
    ICCmodel2 <- sapply(vars2, sum)/total_var2#random intercepts

    if (ICCmodel1>ICCmodel2) { 
      model <- model1
      ICCd <- list(ICCmodel1, "S&I")
    }
    else {
      model <- model2 
      ICCd <- list(ICCmodel2, "I")
    }


    ls <- lsmeans(model, pairwise~condition, adjust="tukey")
    s <- summary(ls$contrasts)

... and other secondary data tidying code.
```

So the question is if this would be a good use of the coefficient. I would appreciate feedback on the possibility of this method. I guess the answer is no as it is normally contingent to a range, but I would be interested if some statistician or someone with the knowledge could answer the why not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICC is helpful to understanding the degree to which the outcome is correlated in your data according to different groups (the random effects you specify). However, I would *not* use it as a decision criteria for whether to use one model or another. You can use model testing for these purposes. The `anova()` command in R is perfectly suited for this. It computes a likelihood ratio test to compare nested models (models in which you can get from one model to the other by constraining parameters to 0). You can also use AIC and BIC as information criteria to compare models. See also [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects).

Comment: Thanks for your input Erik, this really is helpful.